# Problem calling mongoose service with nestjs in jest testing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

Currently i'm trying to test my service but always fails and prints the error, even when the app is running correctly and the service is working

Error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
          at Array.find (<anonymous>)
          at NewsService.findAll (MY_ROUTE\src\news\news.service.ts:28:8)
          at Object.it (MY_ROUTE\src\news\news.service.spec.ts:33:10)
          at Object.asyncJestTest (MY_ROUTE\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmineAsyncInstall.js:106:37)        
          at resolve (MY_ROUTE\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:45:12)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at mapper (MY_ROUTE\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:28:19)
          at promise.then (MY_ROUTE\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queueRunner.js:75:41)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

      at service.findAll.then.catch (news/news.service.spec.ts:39:19)
```

**news.service.spec.ts**

```
import { NewsService } from './news.service';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { News, NewsSchema } from './schemas/news.schema';
import { getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

describe('NewsService', () => {
  let service: NewsService;
  const mockRepository = (...args: any[]) => { };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [NewsService, { provide: getModelToken(News.name), useFactory: mockRepository }],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<NewsService>(NewsService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
  describe('get news', () => {
    it('should get all news', async () => {
      service
        .findAll()
        .then((allNews) => {
          console.log(allNews);
          expect(allNews).toBeDefined();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

**news.schema.ts**

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type NewsDocument = News & Document;

@Schema()
export class News extends Document {
  @Prop({ unique: true })
  id: string;

  @Prop()
  title: string;

  @Prop()
  date: string;
}

export const NewsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(News);
```

**news.service.ts**

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { News } from './schemas/news.schema';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(News.name) private readonly newsModel: Model<News>
  ) {}

  public async findAll(): Promise<News[]> {
    return await this.newsModel
      .find()
      .sort([['date', 'descending']])
      .exec();
  }
}
```

I'm just learning about Jest, but after a lot of research and tests, i couldn't figured out what i'm doing wrong exactly.

---

EDIT
This is the only "decent" thing that i've tried to, but other errors appear. Maybe my whole focus on this is wrong.

```
const mockRepository = (...args: any[]) => {
    findAll: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([
      new News({
        id: '1',
        title: 'title',
        date: 'date',
      }),
    ]);
  };
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined

       5 | 
       6 | @Schema()
    >  7 | export class News extends Document {
         | ^
       8 |   @Prop({ unique: true })
       9 |   id: string;
      10 | 

      at News.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__setSchema (../node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3028:10)
      at new Document (../node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:86:10)
      at new News (news/schemas/news.schema.ts:7:1)
      at InstanceWrapper.mockRepository [as metatype] (news/news.service.spec.ts:13:7)
      at Injector.instantiateClass (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:293:55)
      at callback (../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:77:41)
```

Comment: Your `mockRepository` is nothing at all like the `newsModel` the method you're testing expects. It doesn't have a `find` method, hence the error. Your test doubles need to have the same interface as the thing they're replacing, or they're useless.

Comment: I see... I've been trying to define it many ways but none works, can you help me with it?

Comment: What ways did you try? Give a [mre].

Comment: I edit my post to add the only decent approach that i applied. I feel so lost in this

Comment: You [might want to check out this repo of testing exampls](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)